# Show that $(p \wedge q) \to (p \vee q)$ is a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to show that $(p \wedge q) \to (p \vee q)$ is a tautology. In the fist step in the solution they change this to $\neg(p \wedge q) \vee (p \vee q)$. I have no idea how they did that.

Answer (score 1):

$A \rightarrow B$ is false when $A$ is true and $B$ is false at the same time. Therefore, $A \rightarrow B = \neg (A \land \neg B)=\neg A \lor B.$

With $A=(p \land q)$ and $B=(p \lor q)$ we have

\begin{align*} \neg A \lor B &= \neg (p \land q) \lor (p \lor q) \\ &=(\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor (p \lor q) \\ &= (p \lor \neg p) \lor (q \lor \neg q) \end{align*} (why?). Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this common sense? On says "p **and** q" the other says "p **or** q". If both of them are true, then at least one is true.

Answer (score 0):

$A\rightarrow B$ is false if and only if $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Also, $\neg A \vee B$ is false if and only if $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

So $A\rightarrow B$ and $\neg A \vee B$ are exactly the same thing.

In your case $A=p \wedge q$ and $B=p \vee q$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember $\neg (P \rightarrow Q)$ is $P \wedge \neg Q$ (as the only way $P \rightarrow Q$ can not be true is if $P$ is true but $Q$ isn't).  So $(P \rightarrow Q)$ and  $\neg(P \wedge \neg Q)$ are equivalent statements.

Likewise remember that if it is NOT true that R and S are true than either R is false or S is false.  In other words $\neg (R \wedge S)$ and $\neg R \vee \neg S$ are equivalent statments.

So:

$(p \wedge q) \to (p \vee q) \iff $

$\neg((p \wedge q) \wedge \neg(p \vee q)) \iff $

$\neg(p \wedge q) \vee (p \vee q) \iff $

$(\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee (p \vee q) \iff $

$(\neg p \vee p) \vee (\neg q \vee q)$

which is always true.